# Image with socket io node js

Tags: node.js, image, socket.io

I am trying to do something that sounds quite simple but unfortunately I can't manage to get right.

I just need to stream an image from a file with socket.io.

I have read several links that were either outdated or incomplete and here is where I am right now (not working) :

server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.get('/',function (req,res){res.sendStatus(200)});
app.get('/image',function (req,res){res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html')});


http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("server listening");
}); 

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log("socket connection");
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        fs.readFile('./image.jpeg',function(err,buff){
            if(err){
                console.error(err);
            }
            else{
                socket.emit('image',{image:true,buffer:buff.toString('base64')});
            }
        });
    },1000);
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log("socket deconnection");
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
});
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>IMAGE</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        var socket = io();
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        socket.on('image',function(info){
          if(info.image){
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
              ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            };
            img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + info.buffer;
            console.log("Image received");
          }
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have also tried several other configurations close to this one for the client file but none of them worked.

I read the file at interval because in the real project the image.jpeg file will change at times.

Thank you very much if you can help !

Answer (score 0):

Sending images over a socket is not very efficient. I stumbled upon something similar when I had to send big buffers of game world data to every client. Sending those packets over a socket connection was obviously not an option for me.

I solved it by storing a key that referenced to a specific file on the server, and only sending that key to the client. Then the client would send a request containing the key to a http server, which eventually would respond with the file.

Here is some shortened code just to illustrate:

On the server:

```
...
const files = {};
...

...
function (request, response) { // http request function
    const key = request.url.parse(key);

    const file = fs.readFile(files[key]);

    response.send(file);
}
...

...
function sendFile (socket, file) { // function that sends and stores the key
    const key = generateKey();
    files[key] = file;

    socket.send('key', key);
}
...

...
sendFile(socket, '/path/to/file'); // send key to socket
...
```

This way the big files are being downloaded over http instead of the socket.

On the client:

```
...
socket.on('key', function (key) {
    fetch('/file/' + key, function (response) {
        const file = response.blob(); // blob or whatever
    });
});
...
```

Hope this helps you :D

Comment: It seems a bit overkill for what I need, actually the image I need to display is just a small qr code.